# C# как расширить/изменить функции библиотеки?

Tags: c#, xamarin, библиотеки

В Visual Studio 2017 к проекту на Xamarin подключил библиотеку [Microcharts](https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Microcharts/blob/master/README.md) через nuget manager. Мне требуется некоторые функции изменить в библиотеке, но я не знаю, как получить доступ к коду, чтобы изменить функционал

Например в библиотеки label над точками в графиках пишется вертикально, а мне нужно горизонтально. В библиотеке нет какого-либо свойства/параметра, чтобы изменить направление

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этого делать не нужно. Наследуйся от нужного класса и переопределяй/расширяй методы

Comment: Скачать исходники, разобраться как собрать их.